# Wordpress Error - Needs a fix

Tags: php, wordpress, whitespace

I am moving a Wordpress blog to a new server and have the database in place and the files in place but I am getting an error:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/nasepa/public_html/2009/blog/wp-config.php:1) in /home/nasepa/public_html/2009/blog/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 850

Would appreciate some help deciphering this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first line of your `wp-config.php` file there is some whitespace being sent to the browser. You need to remove this whitespace in order for PHP to send out headers to the browser.

This whitespace could be an `echo` or a `print` or anything spaces that are outside the `<?php` `?>` tags.